# PHP mail with SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm using this code for my mail script with SMTP (without ssl):
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

In line two, the script wants to include a mail.php, but I can't find the code for this mail.php anywhere on this site. When I'm excluding mail.php php tells me that it can't find the class 'mail'.
PEAR Package is installed. What code do I have to include?

Comment: If you are going to just copy something from the web, then why do not use a best approuch? Take a look in this open source project --> http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ (It is very useful).

Answer (score 0):

You must install the PEAR::Mail package as well ("pear install Mail" from the command line)